# Distributed text clustering framework

Tags: java, cluster-analysis, hazelcast, knn

I need a distributed text clustering framework to support algorithms whicomplete set of documents. Applications like carrot2 http://project.carrot2.org/ works on set of documents do in memory computation hence time consuming and very performance efficient. If this kind of text clustering algorithms like lingo,STC, knn etc can run on distributed environment they will be much faster. 
Is there any framework using opensource tools like hazelcast http://www.hazelcast.com/ or is there any specific approach which is more fast and performance efficient.

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Mahout](http://mahout.apache.org/) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... Yes you are right but I guess it works well on Haadoop and moreover I am looking for a bit simpler solution, something which can work on windows forming a cluster and works in a distributed manner.

Answer (score 0):

There are few tools which does this, Mahout is one of them. Mahout supports 3 machine Learning algorithms, recommendation, clustering and classification. **Mahout in action** book by manning does a very good job of explaining this.  Refer to the blog which talks about a use case about how [Mahout and Hadoop distributed file system works](https://krishnasblog.com/2012/06/29/implementing-a-recommender-engine-using-hadoop-and-mahout/)?, the example is more focused on recommendation engine, but it can be applied for clustering as well, as mentioned in **mahout in action** chapter 7. As a precursor to this, I have also written a [Component architecture](https://krishnasblog.com/2012/06/24/hadoop-and-mahout-in-data-mining/) of how each of these tools fit together for a data mining problem.

Mahout will work in standalone mode as well as with Hadoop. The decision to use either one boils down to the size of the historical data that needs to be mined. If the data size is of the order of Terabytes and Petabytes, you typically use Mahout with Hadoop. Weka is another similar open source projects. All these come under a category called machine learning frameworks. I hope it help.